# In Google Sheets, how do I find the month given the day of the year and the year?

Tags: date, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, given the year and the day of year, how do I find the month?

Exemple:

Day 60 from year 2023 is in March, but day 60 from year 2024 is February.

I've tried DATEVALUE("2023-060") thinking it would read the string as an ISO8601 date and returm the internal google sheet number representation, but all I've got was an error.

Answer (score 2):

*You may try:*

```js
=text(date(A2,1,1)+B2-1,"MMMM")
```

[image]